# Error with boost ptr_vector combined with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm trying to get rid of auto_ptr from my code. But im getting this error, and don't know why?

> `no matching function for call to 'boost::ptr_vector<a>::push_back(std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<a>&>::type)'`
>   `note: candidates are:`
>   `...`
>   `note:   'std::unique_ptr<a>' is not derived from 'std::auto_ptr<T>'`

```
{
    boost::ptr_vector<a>& c;

    std::unique_ptr<a> b( new a(x, y) );

    if (!b->isValid())
        return;
    c.push_back(std::move(a));
}
```

Comment: When writing a question please use the preview area to see how it will be displayed. The `<` characters in your question were all treated as HTML, so not displayed correctly. I've fixed it now, but in future please check that your question will display as intended.

Answer (score 6):

It's exactly what the error message tells you: `boost::ptr_vector::push_back` expects an `auto_ptr`, but you provide a `unique_ptr`, which can not be converted to `auto_ptr`.

Since you are converting to `std::unique_ptr`, you won't need `boost::ptr_vector` any more, since it was only meant as a workaround for `auto_ptr`, which could not be stored in containers. Instead use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`.